# Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `somecomponentfunction` of type `function` supplied to `myComponent`, expected `boolean`

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-proptypes

I am facing this warning and am sure its something related to PropTypes

in my parent component **somecomponentfunction** and its returning a boolean and am passing the same to child component

in prent component

```
  somecomponentfunction = () => {
    this.setState({ somecomponentfunction: false })
  }
```

and am passing to childComponet like

```
<myComponent somecomponentfunction={this.somecomponentfunction} />
```

and in child component and am just getting the same in props and am checking the same in PropTypes

```
myComponent.PropTypes={
 somecomponentfunction: PropTypes.bool,
}
```

Can you guys tell what went wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because PropTypes does not execute your function and check if the result returned is a boolean or not. It directly checks what type that prop is carrying.

So `somecomponentfunction` is not a boolean, but a function. If you want to have the result of that function you need to either execute directly

```
somecomponentfunction={this.somecomponentfunction()}
```

or change the propType control to:

```
somecomponentfunction: PropTypes.func
```